React/Vite using createBrowserRouter hosted in a subdirectory does not work without a trailing slash
I'm using React/Vite/Express to build an app that is hosted in a subdirectory. As an example, let's say it's hosted at: https://example.com/my/app/
In my Vite config, I've set base to ./
export default defineConfig({
    base: './',
    build: {
        outDir: './public/build',
    },
    plugins: [react()],
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                implementation: sass,
            },
        },
    }
});

I am also using react-router-dom. Here is my config for createBrowserRouter:
export const router = createBrowserRouter(
    [
        {
            path: '/',
            element: <App />,
            errorElement: <Error />,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/',
                    element: <Home />,
                },
                {
                    path: '/test1',
                    element: <Test1 />,
                },
                {
                    path: '/test2',
                    element: <Test2 />,
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    {
        basename: '/my/app',
    },
);

When I visit the page with the /, it works just fine, e.g. https://example.com/my/app/
However, if I remove the trailing app using https://example.com/my/app, Vite thinks that the base is the parent directory /my/ and uses that as the root. The React JS and CSS then throw 404s.
Is there a way in Vite to fix this without hard-coding the full path as base, or is this something I need to fix on the server to redirect to the URL with the trailing slash?
I'd rather not hard code the base because it will change depending on environments. If that's the best-practice approach, though, I'll go with that solution.
I expected that the application would assume that my/app was a directory. Instead, it seem to be using my/ as the directory. I've tried changing base to . and to an empty string, with no luck.

I think the problem is unrelated to vite configuration. let me guess: you're using react-router-dom with your app? how do you configure it? have you setup basename for the router? related doc

Thanks, Slava. Yes, I'm using createBrowserRouter in react-router-dom. The basename I've set is my/app/. I have also tried my/app but have the exact same issue.

Correct value of basename should be with leading slash, not trailing: "/my/app".  Can you see the same error locally, or only on prod/staging after deployment? If locally too, could you please add your routes configuration to the question? I suspect you just miscofngured index route.

Thanks, just updated with my router configuration. I will test locally tomorrow and report back here.

The issue not only related to vite configuration, but with the react-router configuration.
Try this:
export const router = createBrowserRouter(
    [
        {
            element: <App />,
            errorElement: <Error />,
            children: [
                {
                    index: true,
                    element: <Home />,
                },
                {
                    path: '/test1',
                    element: <Test1 />,
                },
                {
                    path: '/test2',
                    element: <Test2 />,
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    {
        basename: '/my/app',
    },
);


basename value should have leading slash and no trailing slash: '/my/app' - you have already corrected this in your code snippet
for index routes (<Home />in our case) set index: true instead of path: '/'
get rid of path for <App> route

vite config:
export default defineConfig({
    base: '/my/app/',
    ...
});


Thanks Slava - unfortunately, still no luck. I am still seeing in the Network tab that the application is looking for the js/css under the my/ directory and not my/app/ when I leave off the trailing slash from the URL. With the trailing slash, it works fine.

you know, you might be right, base of vite confiuration could actually be the part of the solution: try to set it to /my/app or even /my/app/ and see if it make any difference with the changes i proposed earlier

Thanks! That did it! For what it's worth the path/index changes in the react router didn't seem to affect anything. It works with your config and my original. The fix was to add base with the full path to Vite config and add basename with the full path to react router dom. Thanks for all your help!
